# use pseudo-class as a normal class

Tags: html, css

I have some different navigation boxes on my page, f.e. #home, #about etc and a :hover class for each (changes the bg)

```
#home {
    background-image: url(images/home.jpg);
}

#home:hover {
   background-image: url(images/home_hover.jpg); 
}
```

so now, I want to use the hover image as standard image if the page is selected. F.e. if I'm on the page 'home', I want the box to display the hover image as default instead of the normal. Is there a way to select classes like `<div id="home:hover">` or something like that?

P.S. adding a new class for each box would take a lot of time, as I got pretty much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd put a (common) class on whichever `div` is for the current page - so `<div id="home" class="current">` - and have CSS like:

```
#home:hover, #home.current {
   background-image: url(images/home_hover.jpg); 
}
```